# TextView постепенное обесцвечивание строки с текстом

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте!

Есть textView, текст очень длинный и не умещается во вьюшке, требуется сделать что-то вроде затухания текста, как будто градиент, переход от черного цвета в прозначный. Пробовал в xml задать параметры

> fadingEdge="horizontal"
>
> singleLine="true"
>
> ellipsize="marquee"

Но не сработало.

Пример:

[image]

Comment: @Garf1eld, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Погуглил](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=android%20textview%20ellipsize%20fade) 2 минуты, нашел решение по четвертой ссылке.

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:text="New TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="0"/>
```

В коде нужно вызвать

```
yourTextView.setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое, что приходит в голову, так это положить поверх прозрачную картинку с "забелением" справа.